# Neatest method of replacing a live site with static pages during maintenance?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, .net, application

Alright folks,

Just looking for a little insight into the methods being used by others for the following scenario...

I have a live (.net 3.5) project, which runs from the default folder of IIS7 (mapped to the 'root' of the published wwwroot folder). While we are performing maintenance or upgrades (through a VS built windows installer), I usually replace the application with static pages to explain the system is under maintenance.

We move the published site to a subdirectory (which we isntalled it too), remove old version, install new version, and when we're happy, move it back to the root (replacing the holding pages).

There *must* be a simpler, lower risk way to do this.

How do others out there approach this (or similar) situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IIS I use a method called App_Offline.  More information can be found on [Scott Gu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx) blog.

> The way app_offline.htm works is that
>   you place this file in the root of the
>   application.  When ASP.NET sees it, it
>   will shut-down the app-domain for the
>   application (and not restart it for
>   requests) and instead send back the
>   contents of the app_offline.htm file
>   in response to all new dynamic
>   requests for the application.  When
>   you are done updating the site, just
>   delete the file and it will come back
>   online.
>
> One thing I pointed out in the talk
>   that you want to keep an eye on is a
>   feature of IE6 called "Show Friendly
>   Http Errors".  This can be configured
>   in the Tools->Internet
>   Options->Advanced tab within IE, and
>   is on by default with IE6.  When this
>   is on, and a server returns a non
>   HTTP-200 status code with less than
>   512 bytes of content, IE will not show
>   the returned HTML and instead
>   substitutes its own generic status
>   code message (which personally I don't
>   think is super friendly ).
>
> So if you use the app_offline.htm
>   feature, you should make sure you have
>   at least 512 bytes of content within
>   it to make sure that your HTML
>   (instead of IE's friendly status
>   message) shows up to your users.  If
>   you don't want to have a lot of text
>   show-up on the page, one trick you can
>   use is to just add an html client-side
>   comment with some bogus content to
>   push it over 512 bytes.  For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Site Under Construction</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Under Construction</h1>

    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2>

<!--       
    Adding additional hidden content so that IE Friendly Errors don't prevent
    this message from displaying (note: it will show a "friendly" 404
    error if the content isn't of a certain size).

    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2> 
    <h2>Gone to Florida for the sun...</h2>     
-->
</body>
</html>
```

More discussion about it on our sister site, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm).

Comment: Fantastic answer GregD - exactly what I'm after. Thanks for your input.

Comment: +1 and then some for the note about 404s. IE's decision to display 'friendly' errors seemed infuriatingly arbitrary. That explains a lot.